# why is my function undefined variable: pdo

Tags: php, pdo

why is my function returning undefine variable pdo? i have tried all i could to get it to work but to no avail. even when i put the database connection in same page, still wont work. what could be the problem
thanks

```
            function referralCount($uid,$reflvl)
            {

            $stmt= $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM scraffiliateusr WHERE usrinvby='$uid'");
            $nusrref1 = $stmt->rowCount();
            //$arrusrref1 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);

            $reflvl1=$nusrref1;
            $ttlreflvl2="0";
            $ttlreflvl3="0";

            for ($i=0; $i<$nusrref1; $i++)
            {
            $arrusrref1 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);
                $stmt= $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM scraffiliateusr WHERE usrinvby='$arrusrref1[0]'");
                $nusrref2 = $stmt->rowCount();
                //$arrusrref2 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);
                $ttlreflvl2=$ttlreflvl2+$nusrref2;


                    for ($j=0; $j<$nusrref2; $j++)
                    {
                    $arrusrref2 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);

                    $stmt= $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM scraffiliateusr WHERE usrinvby='$arrusrref2[0]'");
                    $nusrref3 = $stmt->rowCount();
                    //$arrusrref3 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);

                    $ttlreflvl3=$ttlreflvl3+$nusrref3;
                    }
            }
            $reflvl2=$ttlreflvl2;
            $reflvl3=$ttlreflvl3;
            if($reflvl=='1')
            {
            return($reflvl1);
            }
            elseif($reflvl=='2')
            {
            return($reflvl2);
            }
            elseif($reflvl=='3')
            {
            return($reflvl3);
            }

            }
```

Comment: @meagar all you do is mark a question as either duplicate or something but avoid answering questions you might not have an answer to and hinder others that do the pleasure of helping someone out. you coold at least place a link to where the question have been answered before and it might be two different questions altogether!

Comment: That's how this site works. Your question has been asked and answered many times before.

Comment: is there truely, really a question in this world that haven't been asked before?

Comment: Thanks for the reproach Meagar, at least it thought me something too.

Comment: That was not a reproach. I'm trying to tell you how to use this site. Your question was a duplicate of an existing question. If you'd read that question, you would have found your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're running into a problem of variable scope.

See here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Thanks. what i did was place my connection variables inside the function. but i have many functions, so why do i have to do i new connection in every function? why not one connection to work for all the functions?

Comment: but on one of the function i'm having this error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDORow could not be converted to string

Comment: I've fixed the issue. Thanks Mephoros